# HttpClient Authentication in Android

Tags: android, authentication, httpclient

I am trying to access a webservice from android which requires Full authentication. I am using Basic http authentication for this purpose.

I have tried setting UserNamePasswordCredentials as well as setting headers in HttpGet request but all in vein. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

The code I am using for setting headers in HttpGet request:

```
HttpGet requestLogin = new HttpGet(url);               
requestLogin.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString((username+":"+password).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));
```

The code I am using to set UserNamePassword credentials:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, tempClient.getParams());
httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                   AuthScope.ANY,
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username,password));
```

This is exception I am getting while using this code:

```
05-26 17:21:22.234: E/res(1651): <html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/6.0.35 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 401 - Bad credentials</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Bad credentials</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>This request requires HTTP authentication (Bad credentials).</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/6.0.35</h3></body></html>
```

When I use these same credentials on browser, it works. So the credentials are not incorrect. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. I am totally stuck in it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried the manual http header variant, it should work with Base64.Default flag:

```
requestLogin.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " +
    Base64.encodeToString((username+":"+password).getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
```

Comment: I tried it, but it returned "Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand"

Comment: Try to login to the web service using firefox with opened web console. Then click on the request and look at the authorization header. Does it really start with Basic? Compare the following base64 string with the string that is generated by your code.

Comment: Thanks @Torben. My previous code worked for me. The problem was due to "\" character in my username. Decoded it with your help. Thanks a ton.